# dynamically limit the number of chars considered in sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

(Context, thanks to the comments: I need to parse a substring of a longer string.  The length of the substring isn't known until runtime, and the enclosing string is read-only, so writing a null terminator is out.  Since it's on an embedded system, `malloc()` doesn't exist and stacksize is limited.)

Consider the following snippet, which limits the `sscanf()` conversion to the first two chars of "1234":

```
  int d;
  sscanf("1234", "%2d", &d);  // => 12
```

But what if you need to dynamically set that limit dynamically (e.g. for an input string that's not null terminated)?  If it was analogous to `printf()`, you would be able to do this:

```
  int d;
  int len = 2;
  sscanf("1234", "%*d", len, &d);  // doesn't work
```

That doesn't work as expected, since the `*` modifier means to skip the next argument.

The best I've come up with is to use sprintf() to generate the format string for `sscanf()` dynamically:

```
  char fmt[5];
  int d;
  int len = 2;
  snprintf(fmt, sizeof(fmt), "%%%dd", len);  // fmt = "%2d"
  sscanf("1234", fmt, &d);
```

The [Temple of Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/19s5e56xf) tells me that this works.  But is there perhaps a less tortured approach?

### Update

Thanks to a mental nudge from @Shawn, I realized that although the substring I'm working with is variable in length, it *is* bounded to a maximum size.  So I can dispense with scanf() altogether, along the lines of:

```
  char buf[MAX_SUBSTRING_LENGTH];
  memcpy(buf, pointer_to_substring, substring_length);
  int d = atoi(buf);
```

Comment: I would just copy the two characters to another array and use `strtol()` with it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's valid to use an unterminated string even when you use the field size limit, although it probably works in most real implementations.

Comment: Because with `sscanf()` `"An optional '*' assignment-suppression character..."`

Comment: Note that using `sprintf` to generate the format string will result in **"error: format string is not a string literal [-Werror,-Wformat-nonliteral]"** when strict compiler settings are used. Which is to say that for production code, if you want the input interface to be secure, you shouldn't be using any of the `scanf` family of functions.

Comment: If the string is writable there's all sorts of tricks that don't need malloc.

Comment: "Rumtime" :-D Yeah, the best time!

Comment: @shawn The substring is part of a read-only string, so bashing a null terminator into it isn't an option.  But thanks to your original comment, I woke up and realized there's another solution.  See #update in the original post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is pretty much your only option.

As you've found, `scanf` format specifiers don't allow the field width to be specified by a separate argument, unlike `printf` format specifiers.

So the way you're constructing the format string is really the only way to dynamically set the format width for `scanf`.